# CSS - header - always bottom footer and 100% content

Tags: html, css

```
<body> 
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="header">
            HEADER
        </div>
        <div id="inner-wrap">
            <div id="content">
               CONTENT
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            FOTTER
        </div>
    </div> </body>
```

AND CSS:

```
html { height:100%; max-height:100%; }

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
    min-height:100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
* html #wrap { height:100% }

#inner-wrap {
    padding-bottom:50px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#inner-wrap:after {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    clear:both;

}
* html #inner-wrap {
    height:100%;
}

#header
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    height: 16px;
    color: White;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
}
#footer
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    height: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    color: White;
    text-align: center;
}
#content
{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #F5FDEC;  
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

The Problem:

How i can make this: HEADER top 16px,
                     CONTENT dynamic 100% height,
                     FOOTER at end of page

If i give 100% to inner-wrap DIV, them after footer is white space.

Thx

Comment: I think one part of the solution is to add `body { height: 100%;}` also.

Comment: Thanks @Pekka. It was unreadable.

Comment: Sorry, i mist add CSS part with body, body { height: 100%; }, but this have no effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have too many heights going on:

Remove the `min-height` and `max-height` values from your selectors.

Remove the `position: absolute`; from your `#wrap` div.

I made an example [for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/5fryQ/).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when the content gets larger... http://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/5fryQ/8/

Comment: Change the footer position to relative: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/5fryQ/10/ also edited to remove unnecessary rules.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/5fryQ/11/ another example with added jQuery to show you that adding more content will in fact keep the footer where it should be :)

Answer (score 0):

For the footer positioned at the bottom in a fixed position that doesn't move when you scroll the webpage use this:

```
#footer{
position:fixed;
clear:both;
}
```