# 3 row div with 100% height content always

Tags: html, css

i have 3 rows div layout with footer on bottom of page, but i need to have content div always full size from header to footer.
inside the content div i have also a iframe, and i need to have this iframe always at 100% height of conent, then 100% heigt of space between header and footer.
this is my (sample) page:

```
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                    logo
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <h2 id="appname"><img alt="App" src="/images/b_nextpage.png">&nbsp;Home</h2>
                <iframe class="appcont" src="" width="100%" height="100%" name="youriframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="yes" noresize></iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <button name="menu" type="button" id="menuopen"><img alt="App" src="/images/s_process.png">&nbsp;<b>Menu</b>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

this is my css:

```
html, body {
font-family: sans-serif;
padding: 0em;
margin: 0em;
color: #444;
background: #fff;
text-align: center;
height: 100%; /* Important */
width: 100%;
}

#container {
margin: 0px auto;
text-align: center;
height: 100%;
}
```

thanks advance

Comment: if I had the solution to my problem I would not be writing it?
in any case are three days that I look for a solution. If you want to help myself I'm grateful patience but otherwise I really do not understand your argument, we are here to ask and help instill.

Comment: excuse? What's wrong with what I asked? I do not know how to do it even though I have searched through google a solution ... but not I deserve a -1. What kind of thinking is?

Comment: They are downvoting you because you haven't said what your actual problem is, you just posted code and said what you wanted.  What is breaking on your page and what have you tried so far to overcome what is breaking?

Comment: I tried some solutions I found around the internet, for example put the footer fixed at bottom. A  div "clear: both" at the end of container div. I never thought of having to list the dozens of tests I did. Here I saw the most banal questions with answers that would create without any problems.

Comment: I didn't give you a -1, but @huzzah explained my thought process.  Anyway, I did post an answer, but I'm still not completely clear on what you're looking for.

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884636/css-header-always-bottom-footer-and-100-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this as your markup:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">HEADER</div>
    <div id="content">
        <iframe class="appcont" src="" width="100%" height="100%" name="youriframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="yes" noresize></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">hi</div>
</div>
```

and this as your CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

#header {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
}

#content {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:40px;
    top: 40px;
    width:100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #666;
}

#footer {
    height: 40px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Does that get you on your way?

Answer (score 0):

This [Header, Body, Footer with CSS...](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) will show you how.

But really this is simple enough that even if you didn't know...

[image]

Also in the comments section *Elgoog* has given a link to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884636/css-header-always-bottom-footer-and-100-content) already answered on this site.

Please do your research.

Comment: I already tried this solution but the content div (not the container) remains with a height less than 100% of the space between header and footer