# content 100% with footer fixed at bottom

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a template with footer fixed at bottom. I have tried different methods successfully, but now I find it impossible to expand the secondary content div at 100% hight. I have tried Ryan Fait, David Walsh and search other methods. I know it´s a common question but in stackoverflow I have not seen a solution yet.

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/charlyta/hyfUe/

```
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }

    body, html {
        height: 100%;
        }

    #container {
        background: #f00; /* styling only */
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        height: auto !important;
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;



        }

    #content {
        padding-bottom: 100px;
        width: 980px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        margin: 0 auto;
        min-height: 100%;
        margin-top: -20px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(27, 57, 50, 0.44);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 3px rgba(27, 57, 50, 0.44);
        box-shadow:         0px 1px 3px rgba(27, 57, 50, 0.44);
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: relative;
         max-height:100%;
        height:auto !important;
         height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;

        }

    #footer {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #0f0;
        }

        #header {

        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #0f0;
        }

</style>
```

```
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
header
</div>
    <div id="content">
        Your content goes here
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Footer here
    </div>        
</div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Are you trying to create columns or rows?

Comment: No, I am not trying to create columns or rows, just a div 100% height: content

Comment: You want the div to automatically be sized to the height of the content? Is that correct?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884636/css-header-always-bottom-footer-and-100-content?rq=1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884636/css-header-always-bottom-footer-and-100-content?rq=1

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're after but I'll take a stab at it - fake it by applying a transparent background to #content and setting the background you want to see on #content to #container

Comment: Yes I want the div to automatically be sized to the height of the content.

Comment: @Anshuman: I have tryied not successfully

Comment: @Ryan  Excuse me!  I want the div 100% height at the bottom not to the height of the content inside this div

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Retry with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/hyfUe/12/

```
    #container {
        background: #f00; /* styling only */
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        /*position: relative;*/
        /*height: auto !important;*/
        /*min-height: 100%;*/
        height: calc(100% - 120px); /* MAGIC */
    }

    #content {
        border: 3px dashed silver; /* DEBUG */
        padding-bottom: 100px;
        width: 980px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        /*margin: 0 auto; /* REMOVED */
        /*min-height: 100%; /* REMOVED */
        margin-top: -20px;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(27, 57, 50, 0.44);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 3px rgba(27, 57, 50, 0.44);
        box-shadow:         0px 1px 3px rgba(27, 57, 50, 0.44);
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: block;
        height: calc(100% - 170px) !important; /* MAGIC */
        }

    #footer {
        opacity: 0.5; /* DEBUG */
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #0f0;
        }
```

Comment: Yes I have tryied but you can see that the div overflow the bottom. This is the main problem and if I put overflow: hidden my design is cutted

Comment: Ok! :) Just one question, it could be a problem if I put the top-margin nagetive to the content to overlap the header?

Comment: Have you tried ? :) By the way my code was to answer your question, BUT i think it is a better practice to put the footer and the header OUT the container as suggested by the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some changes in css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

#container {
    background: #f00; /* styling only */
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    }

#content {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    width: 980px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(27, 57, 50, 0.44);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 3px rgba(27, 57, 50, 0.44);
    box-shadow:         0px 1px 3px rgba(27, 57, 50, 0.44);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
     max-height:100%;
    height:auto !important;
     height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

#footer {
    display:block;
    position: fixed; /* here is where the magic happens =D */
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #0f0;
    }

    #header {

    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #0f0;
    }
```

The footer can NOT be inside any container if you want to fix it in the bottom, so yout html should be like:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    header
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        Your content goes here
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    Footer here
</div>
```

I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container-for-fix-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
footer {
  height: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* this is what does the trick */
  background-color: black;
}
main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-for-fix-footer">
  header
  <main class="content">
  content
  </main>
  <footer>FOOTER</footer>
</div>
```